# Bootstrap grid layout: force specific cells to always be in the same row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap Grid Layout to show various forms. Cells are assigned width (e.g. 3 of 12 columns) and all of it is configurable. The problem is Label and Field width are supposed to be configured separately. E.g. labelA is width 2, fieldA is width 4, labelB is width 2, fieldB is width 4. This way user will see "2 column" layout: labelA-fieldA-labelB-fieldB.

However there's a problem if user decides to set label and field width to some other value, for example to span all row. User sets label B width to 4 and field B width to 8 expecting it to take whole row. However, in this case he'll get labelA-fieldA-labelB-[empty space for 2 columns] on the first row and fieldB on the second row. Obviously the intended solution would to have labelA-fieldA-[empty space for 6 columns], then labelB-fieldB on the next row. Again, this is all configurable so I need solution for all cases.

A perfect solution would be to have some way to force those cells (label and field) to be non-breakable. Can't find the way to do that.

Another way would be to create a container component with width=label.width+field.width. But then I'll have problems with setting label and field width inside of those containers because I can only set label/field width relative to direct parent and I need to set width relative to the parent's parent. I've heard there are ways to change number of columns in component on render and it'd work if I set number of columns to label.width+field.width. But as far as I understand it's a dirty solution.

The code is in React and this is what's generated for each label and field. InpComp may be any component, doesn't matter in the end. labelWidth and fieldWidth are set by configuration.

```
const labelWidth = this.getLabelWidthFromConfiguration();
const fieldWidth = this.getFieldWidthFromConfiguration();

return (
  <div className={'component-container'}>
    <div className={'col-md-${labelWidth}'}><b>{this.field.attributes.label}</b></div>
    <div className={'col-md-${fieldWidth}'}>
      <InpComp />
    </div>
  </div>);
```

What can I do to this code so that those label and field always end up on the same row?

Comment: could you post some code pls?

Comment: We are not there to show you ideas, we are there to fix code problems, without code we can't do anything. Check the Bootstrap documentation, try something, fail or success, then come there.

Answer (score 0):

what about an if-statement? ;)

you can do something like this:

```
if (lableWidth + fieldWidth !== 6) {
    fieldWidth = 12 - lableWitdh;
}
```

This solution only works for one case (LA+FA = LB+FB = 6). You could set a condition for each case **by your own** using if/else or switch-case.

Like Troyer said, we're not here to show ideas or do your work, we are here to fix code problems. Next time you should try to solve your Problem by your own until you get in stuck and then provide your Code.

Comment: I did try and got stuck. Hoped there's an easy way to unite elements in a non-breakable container so that container itself is not used in width calculations.

Now I can be reasonably sure there's nothing like that and I can go looking for workarounds like the one you proposed. Thank you.